# How to create a new section on the wordpress admin dashboard?

Tags: wp-admin

I'm trying to create a new "section" to store the names and photos of team members. Is there a default way in WP to add this section or is it through the theme? I also want to add another section to showcase the work that has been completed. Seems like this should be easy, but I'm struggling to find the solution. FYI, I'm using Elemenator with Astra theme.

Thanks.

Comment: There's multiple ways to handle this.  You can manually create content using Elementor and your theme, you can install a Custom Post Type plugin, or you can code up your own Custom Post Types and create your own plugin that is theme agnostic.  Going to be really hard to provide you with a specific answer because your question is so open ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at **Custom Post Type**. CPT are what we use if we want to add more data to our website (events, projects...)

https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/

If you're not a developer, take a look at this plugins :

Create a post type in admin
https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Add fields to your post types (in admin)
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

And you can also take a look at some plugin called "Staff" or "Staffer" (based on your needs)